# http.NewRequest() decoding my URL input

Tags: go

When using `http.NewRequest("GET", url , nil)` for URLs that contain a % followed by some number, *example: `https://api.deutschebahn.com/freeplan/v1/journeyDetails/356418%252F128592%252F57070%252F90271%252F80%253fstation_evaId%253D8000261`) Go will encode the string to a "/" in the url. How can I avoid that?

Comment: https://api.deutschebahn.com/freeplan/v1/journeyDetails/356418%252F128592%252F57070%252F90271%252F80%253fstation_evaId%253D8000261

Comment: So it's actually part of the URL path that has the encoded elements. Why is it problematic for you to have it decoded? What is your end-goal?

Comment: because the request that is made is something like this: 1/journeyDetails/244815/84952/449280/143035/80?station_evaId=8098160 for a url string containing this part  244815%2F84952%2F449280%2F143035%2F80%3fstation_evaId%3D8098160

This just leaves me with incorrect requests unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly set the `RawPath` field of the URL struct:

```
req := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://api.deutschebahn.com/freeplan/v1/journeyDetails/356418%252F128592%252F57070%252F90271%252F80%253fstation_evaId%253D8000261", nil)
req.URL.RawPath = "/freeplan/v1/journeyDetails/356418%252F128592%252F57070%252F90271%252F80%253fstation_evaId%253D8000261"
```

This functionality is [documented](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL) for this use case:

> Note that the Path field is stored in decoded form: /%47%6f%2f becomes /Go/. A consequence is that it is impossible to tell which slashes in the Path were slashes in the raw URL and which were %2f. This distinction is rarely important, but when it is, code must not use Path directly.
>
> Go 1.5 introduced the RawPath field to hold the encoded form of Path. The Parse function sets both Path and RawPath in the URL it returns, and URL's String method uses RawPath if it is a valid encoding of Path, by calling the EscapedPath method.

Comment: This led me to solve the issue quickly, but setting Url.RawPath did not work for me. Instead, I used  the QueryEscape(s string) function to escape that part of the url.

Comment: @SparklingWater: Although that may "work" for your case, that's not the correct solution; QueryEscape follows different rules than path escaping. 
At minimum, you should use `PathEscape()` instead. For a proper solution, it would be good to see your actual code, to see how your request is being used.